# how to multiple update row laravel

Tags: php, laravel, adminlte

delete function is all successful
But the update function for all errors
how to fix it

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHyRV.png)

```
public function deleteAll(Request $request)
{
    $ids = $request->ids;
    DB::table("target")->whereIn('id', explode(",", $ids))->delete();
    return response()->json(['success'=>"Products Deleted successfully."]);
}
    public function updateAll(Request $request, $id)
{
    $ids = $request->ids;
            DB::table('target')->whereIn('id',$id)->update(['first_name'=>'test']);
    return response()->json(['success'=>"Products update successfully."]);
}
```

Routes :

```
Route::delete('myproductsDeleteAll', 'AdminController@deleteAll');
Route::post('myproductsUpdateAll', 'AdminController@updateAll');
```

error 
https://pastebin.com/9tA2VDpB

Comment: Please, format your code correctly and include errors within the post, not as an image.

Comment: why $id in whereIn ? you define $ids=>$request->ids.

Comment: use this ...
Route::post('myproductsUpdateAll', 'AdminController@updateAll')->name('edit_post');

and in your form html should contain action like this.. action="{{route('edit_post')}}"

also     don't forget to put {{csrf_field()}}  inside of form html

Comment: I tried the method above ... but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: check in your error log

Answer (score 1):

You may try below code

```
public function updateAll(Request $request, $id)
{
    $ids = $request->ids;
    foreach( $ids as $id ){          
      DB::table('target')->where('id', $id)->update(['first_name'=>'test']);
    }
    return response()->json(['success'=>"Products update successfully."]);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your updateAll function `$id` is not defined and there is `$ids` and you need to explode it as done in `deleteAll` function

```
public function updateAll(Request $request, $id)
{
    $ids = $request->ids;
        DB::table('target')->whereIn('id',explode(",", $ids))->update(['first_name'=>'test']);
    return response()->json(['success'=>"Products update successfully."]);
}
```

Comment: thanks you for helping ..but this don't solve the problem

Comment: May be error is in your html.. post your html code also